# How to connect two vswitches in vsphere client 5?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vswitch

We just had a server installed and the guy doing the installation put our server, internet access etc on one vswitch and then connected the other to our storage server, which obviously our VMs need to be able to access, which is something we can't do while they're on different switches. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like there's a lack of design going on here - when you say 'storage server' do you mean a NAS for file-level access from the VMs or a SAN for storing the VMs on? Also, and please don't take this too harshly, if you don't know how to design and setup vSwitches on ESXi hosts I would say you need to get training before going ahead, it's not too complex but please don't just go changing things blindly.

Comment: Yeah I would love some VMware training, unfortunately being in academia we don't have a whole pile of money to throw around for that, infact we have none so... it's an IBM storewize v3700, aside from that I'm not 100% sure. We're going to store the VMs on our actual server, which has faster harddrives, and then use the storewize 3700 for storing data, we'll probably point the home directories of the linux vms to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess: if you have one physical NIC, your vSwitches are VLANed. If not, they may still be VLANed. Either way, it smells to me like you simply need to give each virtual machine two network interfaces, one to each switch, with appropriate network configurations for each.

BTW, having twice been in academia, not all training costs piles of money. Go buy a book, or heck, even just find some tutorials online. Worst case, go to vmware.com and download and read the manuals.